# Am I using textcomp correctly?

Tags: textcomp

[In a previous question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79880/7880) I was told to use the `textcomp` package if I wanted Old Style Numbers with `tgtermes`. I wanted to know if there were options I could use with it, so I went to it's [ctan page](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcomp), which has the following note:

> The package supports the Text Companion fonts, which provide many text
>   symbols (such as baht, bullet, copyright, musicalnote, onequarter,
>   section, and yen), in the TS1 encoding.
>
> Note that the package has been adopted as part of the LaTeX
>   distribution; the reference here is to the original package, which is
>   now little used (if at all).

Does that mean I'm using it wrong? I just loaded it as I would any other package:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

Is this wrong? If so, how should I be loading it? If correct, where do I look to get documentation on it?

Comment: See section **20.2 The `textcomp` package** (p 94) for the [`textcomp` documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That reference is to the *original* `textcomp` package distributed with the ec companion fonts. It isn't normally used as there is an updated version (with the same name) for LaTeX2e distributed as part of the core LaTeX distribution.

Comment: And just to be sure: This means that we don't *have* to load `textcomp` at all? It will be loaded automatically when running LaTeX?

Comment: @Gaussler you have to load it explicitly, but the quoted description is describing a different obsolete package of the same name, the one you get if you use `\usepackage{textcomp}` comes from the core latex/base distribution not from a separate textcomp package distribution.

Comment: I'm still confused. How do we load the correct, up-to-date `textcomp` if not with `\usepackage{textcomp}`?

Comment: @Merchako At the time I wrote this (8 years ago)  you did need to use `\usepackage{textcomp}`  But unrelated to the issue of this question if you have the 2020 latex release you do not need the package at all the commands are defined already in the core latex format. But loading it does no harm.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by updating all the TeX Live packages following [this page](https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html)

```
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh -- --upgrade
tlmgr update --self --all
luaotfload-tool -fu
```